# Maximum Entropy Policy Gradient Derivation

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, gradient-descent, policy-gradients, derivation

I am reading through the paper on [Reinforcement Learning and Control as Probabilistic Inference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.00909): Tutorial and Review by Sergey Levine. I am having a difficulty in understanding this part of the derivation on Maximum Entropy Policy Gradients (Section 4.1)
[image]

Note that in the above derivation, the term H(q(thetha(at|st))) should have been log (qthetha(at|st)), and that log refers to log base e (i.e. natural logarithm). In the first line of gradient, it should have been r(st,at) - log(qthetha(at|st)).

In particular, I cannot understand how the second summation term from t'=t to t'=T in the second line arises in the derivation. I managed to derive the formula by expanding the definition of expectation, but the result that I got do not have the second summation term. Can anyone give me ideas on where this second summation term comes from mathematically?

Answer (score 1):

Writing the objective in a different way may be helpful.

If we **only focus on the reward part** and ignore the entropy part since the focus in the question is about the second summation, the original objective is
$$
J(\theta)=\sum_{t=1}^T\mathbb{E}_{(s_t,a_t)\sim q(s_t,a_t)}[r(s_t,a_t)]
$$

If we look at it from the perspective of the full trajectory $\tau$, just like the ELBO in the paper Eq.19, the objective is
$$
J(\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim q_\theta(\tau)}\left[\sum_{t=1}^Tr(s_t,a_t)\right]
$$

Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_\theta J(\theta)&=\nabla_\theta\sum_\tau q_\theta(\tau)\sum_{t=1}^T r(s_t,a_t)\\
&=\sum_\tau \nabla_\theta q_\theta(\tau)\sum_{t=1}^T r(s_t,a_t)\\
&=\sum_\tau q_\theta(\tau)\nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(\tau)\sum_{t=1}^T r(s_t,a_t)\\
&=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim q_\theta(\tau)}\left[\nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(\tau)\sum_{t=1}^Tr(s_t,a_t)\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Since $q_\theta(\tau)=q(s_1)\prod_{t=1}^T q(s_{t+1}|s_t,a_t) q_\theta(a_t|s_t)$,
$$
\nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(\tau)=\sum_{t=1}^T \nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(a_t|s_t)
$$

Then
$$
\nabla_\theta J(\theta)=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim q_\theta(\tau)}\left[\sum_{t=1}^T \nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(a_t|s_t) \sum_{t=1}^Tr(s_t,a_t)\right]
$$

That is **where the second summation comes from**.

Since policy at time $t'$ cannot affect reward at time $t$ when $t<t'$ (**causality**),
$$
\begin{aligned}
\nabla_\theta J(\theta)&=\mathbb{E}_{\tau\sim q_\theta(\tau)}\left[\sum_{t=1}^T \nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(a_t|s_t) \sum_{t'=t}^Tr(s_t',a_t')\right]\\
&=\sum_{t=1}^T \mathbb{E}_{(s_t,a_t)\sim q(s_t,a_t)}\left[\nabla_\theta \log q_\theta(a_t|s_t) \sum_{t'=t}^Tr(s_t',a_t')\right]
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: wow how long did it take you to format this answer?